# How to detect Unavailability or Unauthenticated of Laravel Auth Sanctum Token for Mobile API

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

### BACKGROUND

So I created a security process on `routes/api.php` in Laravel using `auth:sanctum` for mobile APIs like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('profile', [UserController::class, 'profile']);
    Route::post('profile_update', [UserController::class, 'updateProfile']);
    Route::post('logout', [UserController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

I know to be able to access the APIs in it, then I need a `PersonalAccessToken` which can be generated like this:

```
$user = M_CRM_CUSTOMER::where('indexs', $user_indexs)->first();
$tokenResult = $user->createToken($request->mobile)->plainTextToken;
```

Which is where the code will populate the records in the `personal_access_tokens` table which is served automatically in the initial Laravel migration

```
Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->morphs('tokenable');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
    $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

### CASE

Technically, as long as the Token is in the Database or as long as it hasn't expired, then we can access/use it against the APIs in the group, right?
[image]

If you try to access the APIs in the group using Postman, it will work.

Now, if the User revokes the Token, using:
`$token = $request->user()->tokens()->delete();`

Then if we try to access the APIs contained in the group using Postman, **it will result in a failed display in the form of HTML code** from the Laravel login page.
[image]

Maybe for web users this is helpful and viewable, but for Mobile API users?
There will definitely be an error.

### EXPECTATIONS

My point is how do I know **if the User is authenticated** OR has a **PersonalAccessToken using Sanctum**?
So that I can create a simple return message, in case the User is not authenticated.

#### Try 1

Maybe because I'm using `auth:sanctum`, I can't use [Laravel's manual authentification](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users) to know if the User is authenticated or not, like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // Do something if user is authenticated
}
```

It always returns that the User is not authenticated, even though I've generated Sanctum's token generator like this:

```
$user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
```

#### Try 2

I have also tried with detect like this:

```
if (!$request->user()->tokens()->where('tokenable_id', Auth::id())->first()) {
    return 'Not Authenticated';
} else {
    return 'Authenticated';
}
```

The token is detected anyway, but is this the right way?

Please **enlighten me**, or am I just misunderstanding the concept and using the functions of the Auth Sanctum?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to display the error return form by setting it to the form of `application/json`, like this *(If you are using Postman)*
[image]